# STSADM Restore Command Error - 'Attempted to read past the end of the stream'

Tags: error, restore, stsadm, server

I have setup a new server on Windows Server 2012 (Domain Controller Included) and when i perform a STSADM restore command on the 80 site. I got the following message:

> Attempted to read past the end of the stream.

I have attached the screen shot as well..

[image]

Any ideas on why I got this message??

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of the issue:

**The backup file was corrupt**. Hope this will help someone save a lot of time scratching his head :)!